# How do I set a localized name for a folder?

Tags: filesystem, internationalization

I want to give a folder a localized name.  In one of Apple's articles, I found out that the ".localized" file (e.g., in ~/Downloads) is responsible for indicating this, but all of the .localized files are empty (length 0).  I can't find any documentation for the content of this file, or even if it can have any at all.

How can I make a folder whose name is "One", but whose Spanish name is "Uno"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this page explains what you have to do:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemAdvancedPT/LocalizingtheNameofaDirectory/LocalizingtheNameofaDirectory.html